# How can I know if the packet I send is received when I'm using UDP?

Tags: networking, tcp, udp

I know UDP is not a two-way communication between client & server. However, if I send a packet to clients from a server, how can I know that my packet reach it's destination?

Comment: Probably better asked here: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You use an application-layer protocol that can acknowledge receipt of data. You could use an existing protocol, or develop your own. Also, with real-time traffic, e.g. VoIP or video, you do not want acknowledgement. Real-time protocols should understand that traffic will be lost and compensate for it. For example, VoIP packets that are lost should not be requested to be resent because the data would be useless when it arrives. You don't want sound after the surrounding sound has been played.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to be sure that the data you've send are received (and processed) by the server application is to let the server application explicitly acknowledge the data in a reply.

Note that contrary to a comment to your question it will not help to use TCP instead of UDP to get a more reliable transport: while your OS kernel will does its best to deliver data with TCP (instead of just trying once with UDP) it can neither guarantee the delivery (since connectivity might break) nor does it care if the server application itself has read and maybe also processed the data. The only way to know that the application has successfully read the data is to let the application itself say so.